# If an eigenvalue of an integer matrix lies on the unit circle, must it be a root of unity?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a real matrix with integer entries, and suppose $z$ is a complex eigenvalue of $A$ with $|z| = 1$. Is it true that $z$ is either an odd or even root of unity? That is, must there exist an $m$ such that $z^m = 1$?

Another way of asking the same thing is (I think) whether complex units with an irrational argument are algebraic numbers.

**EDIT**: The accepted answer shows this is not true. However, I'm still interested under what conditions can this be claimed about $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $p(x)=x^4-2x^3-2x+1$. Its eigenvalues are the roots of $p(x)$, two of which are complex (non-real) numbers with absolute value $1$, none of which is a root of unity.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. However, I'm still interested in the conditions under which $A$ cannot have complex units that are not roots of unity. Any pointers?

Comment: I would love to help here, but I have no idea.

Comment: $$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&0 \\
1&1&0&1 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$ x^4 - 2 x^3 - 2x + 1 $$  at his more recent question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393377/if-a-real-matrix-has-a-complex-eigenvalue-on-the-unit-circle-when-is-it-a-root