# If a real matrix has a complex eigenvalue on the unit circle, when is it a root of unity?

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots-of-unity

Let $A$ be a real matrix with integer entries, and suppose $z$ is a complex eigenvalue of $A$ with $|z|=1$. As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3391484/307720), $z$ need not be a root of unity (i.e. there need not exist an $m$ with $z^m = 1$). Under which conditions on $A$ can this be guaranteed? What if all of $A$'s entries are either $1$ or $0$?

Answer (score 1):

all 1 and 0 is not good enough. This first characteristic polynomial is the one given by Jose Carlos Santos in your earlier question [If an eigenvalue of an integer matrix lies on the unit circle, must it be a root of unity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3391472/if-an-eigenvalue-of-an-integer-matrix-lies-on-the-unit-circle-must-it-be-a-root)

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&0 \\
1&1&0&1 \\
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$ x^4 - 2 x^3 - 2x + 1 = \left(x^2 - (1 + \sqrt 3)x+1 \right) \left(x^2 - (1 - \sqrt 3)x+1 \right)$$
Characteristic polynomial can be solved by dividing by $x^2,$ then writing as a quadratic function of $x + \frac{1}{x}$

Here is another one, the characteristic polynomial is once again palindromic. The roots can be found by the same trick.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&1 \\
1&1&1&0 \\
0&1&0&1 \\
1&1&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$ x^4 - 2 x^3 - 2 x^2 - 2x + 1 = \left(x^2 - (1 + \sqrt 5)x+1 \right) \left(x^2 - (1 - \sqrt 5)x+1 \right) $$

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? m =    [1,1,1,0;1,1,0,1;0,1,0,0;0,0,1,0]
%1 = 
[1 1 1 0]

[1 1 0 1]

[0 1 0 0]

[0 0 1 0]

? charpoly(m)
%2 = x^4 - 2*x^3 - 2*x + 1
? 
?
```